# html selection enable disable attribute

Tags: javascript, php

I have three selection boxes in one of my web page. I set the two of it to be dependent on the value of the first one like when the value of select a is 1 then the other two will be enabled and I did but the problem lies after I press the submit because after that I cannot clicked the other two even if the value of the first s still selected to 1. Here is my select boxes:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
    <label>Department</label>
    <select class="field" id="cmbdept" name="dept" onchange="handleSelect()">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
            try{
                $query1 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM departments");
                $query1->execute(); 
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                exit();
            }
            while($r = $query1->fetch()) {
                extract($r);
                echo <<<EOL
                    <option value='$Deptname'>$Deptname</option>
                EOL;
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('cmbdept').value = "<?php echo $_GET['dept'];?>";
    </script>

    <label><strong>Section</strong></label> 
    <select id="cmbsection" name="section" disabled="disabled">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
            try {
                $query2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM section");
                $query2->execute();
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                exit();
            }
            while($s = $query2->fetch()) {
                extract($s);
                echo "<option value='$sectionName'>$sectionName</option>";                          
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('cmbsection').value = "<?php  echo $_GET['section'];?>";
    </script>

    <label><strong>Line</strong> </label>
    <select id="cmbline" name="line" disabled="disabled">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
            try{
                $query3 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM line");
                $query3->execute();
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                exit();
            }
            while($t = $query3->fetch()) {
                extract($t);
                echo "<option value='$lineName'>$lineName</option>";                                                
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('cmbline').value = "<?php echo $_GET['line'];?>";
    </script>

    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('from').value = "<?php echo $_GET['from'];?>";
    </script>

    <label for="to">To</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('to').value = "<?php echo $_GET['to'];?>";
    </script>

    <br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

and here is the javascript that i use:

```
function handleSelect() {
    var item1 = document.getElementById("cmbdept");
    var item2 = document.getElementById("cmbsection");

    if(item1.value == 'SEWING') {
        document.getElementById('cmbsection').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('cmbline').disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('cmbsection').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('cmbline').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doubt it will solve your issue but your `heredoc` close is invalid according to the manual. See invalid example 1: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: When you are writing `<<<EOL` and closing with `EOL` wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you are trying to do. The key here is to limit repetitions in your script. If you are doing things over and over again, like the same database call sequence, that is a signal you should be creating a function (or class) to go in place of it:

**/functions/form.php**

```
<?php
// Since you are doing the same query sequence over and over,
// just do it once and make it reusable
function fetch_query($con,$sql,$keyname = false)
    {
        try{
                $query = $con->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute(); 
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                // Let's not announce issues to users. You reveal the error
                // only if the user is logged in as an administrator otherwise
                // You should be able to just return an empty array so the
                // web app keeps on going (unless you really want to exit, you can)
                //echo $e->getMessage();
                return array();
            }

        while($r = $query->fetch()) {
                $result[]   =   (isset($r[$keyname]))? $r[$keyname] : $r;
            }

        return (!empty($result))? $result : array();
    }
// Create a get_departments function
function get_departments($con)
    {
        return fetch_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `departments`","Deptname");
    }
// Create a get_section function
function get_section($con)
    {
        return fetch_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `section`","sectionName");
    }
// Create a get_line function
function get_line($con)
    {
        return fetch_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `line`","lineName");
    }
// Create a sanitizer function that checks for set array keys
function to_page($array = false,$key = false)
    {
        if(!is_array($array))
            return false;

        return (isset($array[$key]))? htmlspecialchars($array[$key],ENT_QUOTES) : "";
    }
```

**/form.php (or whatever the name of this page is)**

```
<?php
// include the php functions above
include_once("functions/form.php");
?>
<!-- INCLUDE JQUERY LIBRARIES IF NOT ALREADY SET -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
    <label>Department</label>
    <select class="field" id="cmbdept" name="dept">
        <option value="">Select</option>
<?php   foreach(get_departments($con) as $Deptname) { 
?>      <option value="<?php echo $Deptname; ?>"><?php echo $Deptname; ?></option>
<?php   }
?>
    </select>
    <label><strong>Section</strong></label> 
    <select id="cmbsection" name="section" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">Select</option>
<?php   foreach(get_section($con) as $sectionName) { 
?>      <option value="<?php echo $sectionName; ?>"><?php echo $sectionName; ?></option>
<?php   }
?>
    </select>
    <label><strong>Line</strong> </label>
    <select id="cmbline" name="line" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">Select</option>
<?php   foreach(get_line($con) as $lineName) { 
?>      <option value="<?php echo $lineName; ?>"><?php echo $lineName; ?></option>
<?php   }
?>
    </select>

    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" value="<?php echo to_page($_GET,"from");?>" />
    <label for="to">To</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to" value="<?php echo to_page($_GET,"to");?>" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
<?php
    // Fetch the values of the get
    $set['line']    =   to_page($_GET,"line");
    $set['cmbdept'] =   to_page($_GET,"dept");
    $set['section'] =   to_page($_GET,"section");
    // Remove empty 
    $set            =   array_filter($set);
    // If there are any left, loop through them
    if(!empty($set)) {
        foreach($set as $idName => $value) { 
?>$('#<?php echo $idName; ?>').val('<?php echo $value; ?>');
<?php   }
    }
?>
    // Run on load
    handleSelect();
    // Run on change
    $("#cmbdept").change(function() {
        handleSelect();
    });
});
function handleSelect()
    {
        var item2 = $("#cmbsection");
        var item1 = $("#cmbdept");

        if(item1.val() == 'SEWING') {
            item2.prop("disabled",false);
            $("#cmbline").prop("disabled",false);
        } else {
            item2.prop("disabled",true);
            $("#cmbline").prop("disabled",true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try your suggestion and hope it will help solve my issues.

Comment: I know you marked my answer right but did It work as you were wanting it to?

Comment: as you stated I might having problems in multiple declaration of my query so when i checked your answer it might solve my problem. Sorry i can't  test your code just yet because I am solving my other issue of phpexcel having blank data here is the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071987/no-data-written-in-excel-using-phpexcel?noredirect=1#comment53962051_33071987