# No data is written into Excel

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpexcel

I have the following code:

```
require 'PHPExcel.php';
require 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
require 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$user = "root";
$pass = "admin";
$host = "localhost";
$db = "hrtms";

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

try{
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$con->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
exit();
}

try{
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM emptb WHERE Department =  'ADMIN/OFFICE' ORDER BY id ASC");
$query->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
exit();
}
$rowCount = 1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
while($row = $query->fetch())
{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount,$row['EmpID']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount,$row['Lastname'] . ", " . $row['Firstname']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount,$row['SectionName']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount,$row['LineName']);
    $rowCount++;
}
$excelWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$excelWriter->save('sample.xlsx');
```

Though its syntax is correct but it doesn't write any data to excel. Please help me because I only have 2 days deadline. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If your code is compiling and completing successfully, then perhaps there's no data returned from the SQL query?? Also, should your calls to `SetCellValue` use A, B, C and then D, not A, A, A, A. Otherwise you're always writing to the same cell on each row.

Comment: I put echo statement to check if my query is wrong but it returns all containing data from the table so it might have something to do with my phpexcel syntax.

Comment: You are writing all on the row A, you should put 'A' for EmpID, 'B' for Lastname, and so on.

Comment: Thanks my fault. I solved the problem leonardo was right when i changed the succeeding cells from A to other letters it already writes.